# Is building training data set from unlabeled data considered as a scientific contribution?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, dataset, academia

Is building a training data set, from unlabeled data, for a machine learning classifier considered as a scientific contribution?

Comment: What do you mean by "scientific contribution"?

Comment: You should do and overview of related work regarding this topic. This will give you a quick overview of where you stand and if your solution is of scientific value. If I quote one of my professors: "_If there is no related work regarding some topic, you are either trying to accomplish something brilliant or something stupid_".

Answer (score 2):

You will very likely not be able to publish such a labeling as a standalone journal article - it is simply too routine and does not advance scientific knowledge as such.

If this labeling is done as part of a larger machine learning project, the contribution would be the larger project.

If, finally, there was one person in a team whose main contribution to a larger ML project was labeling unlabeled data, this may be sufficient for coauthorship; especially if the labeling took a significant amount of time and if this person also actively reviewed the manuscript etc. This would need to be clarified with the other authors. It seems to be on a par with the question when someone is a coauthor whose main contributions were writing software, or doing the statistics.

---

You may get better answers at [Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions). Consider editing your question to clarify what exactly you are asking and then potentially flagging it for migration. ([Please do not simply cross-post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/256777))